# do while loop, InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am working on a program that calculates a users BMI. I can't figure out why my do while loop is not working for my InputMismatchException. The first time it will say that it is incorrect but if you enter it in a second time it will crash. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class W8
{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      //Utilities
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Variables
      double height = 0.0;
      double weight = 0.0;
      boolean error = false;
      double bmi = 0.0;  

      do 
      {
         try 
         {
            error = false;
            while (height <=0)
            {
               System.out.println("Enter height in inches:");
               height = in.nextDouble();
            }
         } 
         catch (InputMismatchException e) 
         {
            in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.");
            System.out.println("Re-enter height in inches:");
            height = in.nextDouble();
            error = true;
         } 
      }while (error);

      do
      {
         try
         {
            error = false;
            while (weight <=0)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter weight in pounds:");
            weight = in.nextDouble();
            }
         } 
         catch (InputMismatchException e)
         {

            in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Invalid pounds value. Must be a decimal number.");
            System.out.println("Re-enter weight in pounds:");
            weight = in.nextDouble();
            error = true;
         } 
      }while (error);

      //bmi calculation
      bmi = (weight/(height*height))*703;

      //Outputs
      System.out.println("Height = " +height+".");
      System.out.println("Weight = " +weight+".");
      System.out.println("Body mass index = " +bmi+ ".");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your inputs.

Comment: `nextDouble()` isn't going to give you an error on non-decimal numbers.

Comment: So here is a sample session of what we supposed to be able to do: Enter height in inches: hi
Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.
Re-enter height in inches: 0
Invalid inches value. Must be positive.
Re-enter height in inches: 69.25
Enter weight in pounds: dog
Invalid pounds value. Must be a decimal number.
Re-enter weight in pounds: -3
Invalid pounds value. Must be positive.
Re-enter weight in pounds: 150.5
height = 69.25"
weight = 150.5 pounds
body mass index = 22.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    // Utilities
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Variables
    double height = 0.0;
    double weight = 0.0;
    boolean error = false;
    double bmi = 0.0;
    System.out.println("Enter height in inches:");
    while (height <= 0) {
        try {
            height = in.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            height = -1;
            System.out
                    .println("Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.");
            System.out.println("Re-enter height in inches:");
            in.nextLine();
            error = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter weight in inches:");
    while (weight <= 0) {
        try {
            weight = in.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            weight = -1;
            System.out
                    .println("Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.");
            System.out.println("Re-enter weight in inches:");
            in.nextLine();
            error = true;
        }
    }
    // bmi calculation
    bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703;

    // Outputs
    System.out.println("Height = " + height + ".");
    System.out.println("Weight = " + weight + ".");
    System.out.println("Body mass index = " + bmi + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called automatic type promotion in Java. Here are the basic rules for type promotion

**Type Promotion Rules**

Widening conversions do not lose information about the magnitude of a value. For example, an int value is assigned to a double variable. This conversion is legal because doubles are wider than ints. Java's widening conversions are

> From a byte to a short, an int, a long, a float, or a double
>
> From a short to an int, a long, a float, or a double
>
> From a char to an int, a long, a float, or a double
>
> From an int to a long, a float, or a double
>
> From a long to a float or a double
>
> From a float to a double

double is the widest primitive type, and it is because of these ruels that when you input integers in your program they are promoted as double